# How to substitute a keypress with another in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my localized rails app, the default decimal mark is a comma (,) instead of a dot (.)

for ex. 1.000.000,56

When my users enter numerical values, they prefer to use the numerical pad of the keyboard for speed reasons. HOWEVER the numerical pad features a DOT instead of a COMMA so the whole process is hindered.

So my question is:

Is there a way to programmatically enter a comma inside a text input when a user hits the dot in the numerical keypad?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the above answer, but using keydown you can preventDefault, which will stop it entering the value in the first place. Then it's up to you how you append the comma:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which === 110){ //check for numpad '.'
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the event entering text

        var $inputValue = $(this).val();

        $(this).val($inputValue + ','); //add your append logic to add comma
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this on the control where this value is entered

```
$('#searchbox input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){//here in your case it would be keycode of '.'
        // Enter pressed... do anything here...
    }
});
```

You can use this link to find out the required keycode http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/dot-full-stop-ascii-code-46.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the jQuery `e.which` method to obtain the correct keycode and to avoid the mess resulted in different methods for recognizing the key press events.

```
var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode
```

Here is the code which transform the dots to coma on enter:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){    
    if (e.which == '13') {                
        $('input').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace('.', ',');
        });           
    }
});
```